# Simple way to enumerate the files in a fileset in phing

Tags: phing

I am new to phing and trying to verify if my `build.xml` works as expected. I am looking for a convenient way to enumerate the files in a phing `fileset`.

The only thing that I've been able to get working is `foreach` (like in [how to iterate (loop) through directories in phing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451206/how-to-iterate-loop-through-directories-in-phing/4459526#4459526)). However, it feels way too complex: I have to create a subtask, and phing gets called once for every file, making the outupt list hard to parse visually.

Any better alternatives? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Phing 2.4.8, the `<echo>` task supports filesets:
http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/792

Comment: Awesome! A ticket by itself would have been great and beyond all expectations. A ticket and an accepted patch cannot get better. Impressed. Happy. Thanks a lot. Happy. Really. Very happy. Very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no better way. You could grep the output, though :)

```
<task name="dummy">
  <foreach param="filename" absparam="absfilename" target="echoFilesetFile">
    <fileset refid="co"/>
  </foreach>
</task>

<target name="echoFilesetFile">
  <echo>file: rel:${filename}|abs:${absfilename}</echo>
</target>
```

then `$ phing dummy | grep 'file:'`